# Rails 3 has_many :through + join table conditions / scoping

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I'm working on an app that has the models `User` and `Project`, and `User` can be assigned to multiple `Project`s, via `ProjectUser`, with a role (e.g. Developer, Designer).

```
Project
  has_many :project_users
  has_many :users, :through => :project_users

User
  has_many :project_users
  has_many :projects, :through => :project_users

ProjectUser (user_id, project_id, role)
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
```

I can call `@project.users` and `@user.projects`, but since there are varying roles, I'd like to be a bit more specific with the relations. Ideally, I want to be able to do the following:

```
@project.developers
  # returns @project.users, but only where ProjectUser.role = 'Developer'

@project.designers << @user
  # creates a ProjectUser for @project, @user with role 'Designer'

@user.development_projects
  # returns projects where @user is assigned as a 'Developer'

@user.design_projects << @project
  # creates a ProjectUser for @project, @user with role 'Designer'
```

I currently have the following code:

```
has_many :developers, :through => :project_users, :source => :user,
                      :class_name => "User",
                      :conditions => ['project_users.role = ?','Developer']
```

But this only really does the fetching one-way, and doesn't give me much else - I can't build or assign or anything.

I'm attempting some more complex logic which I think might work, but would appreciate some pointers:

```
has_many :developer_assignments, :source => :project_user,
                                 :conditions => { :role => 'Developer' }
has_many :developers, :through => :developer_assignments # class_name?
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

`has_many` accepts a block that can define/override methods for the association. This will allow you to create a custom method for `<<`. I've created a small example for you, you could create build in a similar fashion.

```rb
# Project.rb
has_many :developers, :through => :project_users, :source => :user,
         :conditions => "project_users.role = 'developer'" do
         def <<(developer)
           proxy_owner.project_users.create(:role => 'developer', :user => developer)
         end
       end
```

Now you can add a new developer to your your project with: `@project.developers << @user` as requested. `@project.developers` gives you all the developers.

If you have a lot of roles, it might be useful to create these has_many statements dynamically.

```rb
# Project.rb
ROLES = ['developer','contractor']

ROLES.each do |role|         
  self.class_eval <<-eos
    has_many :#{role.downcase}s, :through => :project_users, :source => :user,
           :conditions => "project_users.role = '#{role}'" do
             def <<(user)
               proxy_owner.project_users.create(:role => '#{role}', :user => user)
             end
           end
  eos
end
```

Looking back at everything above it doesn't seem like *the rails way* of doing things. Scoping this should make it possible to get the build and create commands working without redefining everything.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solves my problem, but doesn't do so in the way I was hoping - by using scopes on the `ProjectUsers` model.

Declaring `:conditions => "project_users.role = '#{role}'"` doesn't seem very railsy, as I would have liked call something like `:conditions => { :scope => :developer }`. I'm still certain this is possible somehow. Either way, I'm awarding you the bounty for your effort, though this answer won't be marked as correct. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Thanks. I was really expecting `has_many :designers, :through => :project_users, :source => :user, :conditions => {:project_users => {:role => :designer}}` to work automatically, but apparently nested conditions hashes are not scoped with build and create. This was the best I could come up with.

Comment: what is `proxy_owner` in the above? is that reference to the other side of the assiociation, similar to `proxy_association` that you get with `:extend`?

Comment: `proxy_owner` refers to the instance of (in this case) a `Project` object.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a combination of RoR's [single table inheritance](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html) and [named scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

Take a look at the following [article](http://www.alexwestholm.com/tech/rails-single-table-inheritance-and-polymorphic-associations-some-simple-examples/) for a nice example about polymorphic associations. This should help you with achieving the following:

```
@project.developers
  # returns @project.users, but only where ProjectUser.role = 'Developer'

@project.designers << @user
  # creates a ProjectUser for @project, @user with role 'Designer'
```

Scopes will give you a clean way to implement `@user.development_projects` but there may be more trickery required to get the `<<` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [scopes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html) yet? It doesn't let you do <<. But it simplifies querying.

**Try:**

```
Project
  scope :developers, lambda {
    includes(:project_users).where("project_users.role = ?", "developer")
  }
```

You will be able to get all developers using: `@project.developers`