# Rails complex has_many and has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I have 4 models: Drawer, Folder, FolderDocument and Document as follows:

```
class Drawer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :folders #Drawer has many folders
end

class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :drawer
  has_many :folder_documents

  # Folder has a "version" attribute which reflects the latest version
  # Use proc to give back latest version by default e.g. folder.documents or folder.documents(5) will give back a specific version.      
  has_many :documents, :through => :folder_documents, :conditions => proc { |v = nil|
         v ||= self.version
         "documents.active IS TRUE AND version = #{v}"
       }, :uniq => true 
end

class FolderDocument < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Has a version attribute
  belongs_to :document
  belongs_to :folder
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :folder_documents
  has_many :folders, :through => :folder_documents
end
```

My problem is that I cant create a

```
has_many :documents, :through => :folders
```

on class Drawer as the proc conditions (for documents from FolderDocument) cant be calculated as "version" is calculated in context of Drawer not the intermediate folder association.

Is there way I can do this without creating another model between Folder and FolderDocuments called FolderVersion?

EDIT: Objective is to get all documents that belong to a folder for the current version (version in folders).

Comment: I believe you have some typos here `has_many :drawers #Drawer has many folders`

Comment: Could you explain a bit more clearly what you are trying to achieve? There might be some kind of very different solution out there. :-D

Comment: I am trying to find ALL documents that belong to a folder for the most current version.

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7753162/178651 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5856838/178651

Comment: @GaryS.Weaver: How do I add something to the join condition if I add a scope to the has_many?

Comment: @ankimal So, if `folder.documents` then folders.version = folders_documents.version and documents.active is true, but if `folder.documents(x)`, then the condition would check that folders_documents.version is equal to x and documents.active is true?

Comment: Sorry, I meant folder_documents as the table name (was thinking about habtm default table name by accident). Wouldn't it work to just change the condition above to `documents.active IS TRUE AND folder_documents.version = #{v}`? You can also use scope on the joining model or do things like pass a block into the has_many to redefine the association methods (like `<<(some_var)`, etc. as mentioned in the answers to the questions I linked to.

Comment: @GaryS.Weaver The problem with the proc conditions is that they are evaluated in the scope of the calling class. For Folder.first.documents and Folder.first.documents(2) works great. But, Drawer.documents fails as #{v} is evaluated in context of Drawer not Folder.

Comment: @ankimal Drawer doesn't have a documents association in the model code you listed. Also that isn't the question you asked, you said "EDIT: Objective is to get all documents that belong to a folder for the current version (version in folders)." but that isn't what you just said, since apparently getting access to documents from Drawer is also what you are looking for?

Comment: If you already took a look at the previous links I mentioned, take a look also at http://stackoverflow.com/q/2462203/178651 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/4632472/178651. But, I'd think if you were to specify the table name in the condition SQL fragment as I mentioned in previous comment (`folder_documents.version = #{v}` vs. `version = #{v}`), you could just use a similar association and proc in whichever class you need it (just changing table names, etc. as needed).

Comment: Also, make sure `v` is sanitized properly to avoid SQL injection.