# rails associations with plural, possible, foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example I have 2 players game, with future to have more than one game in the same time. 
I need to create associations that will give me the opportunity to simply call user.games and it will return all games where that user is involved, as first_user_id or second_user_id.

table games
desk
first_user_id
second_user_id

table users
id

Model User
has_namy ??

Comment: i haven't tried this yet but you can look at the `finder_sql` for has_many.  I'm pretty sure that's what you need.

Comment: Thank you, but I think there must be easier or more right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you are asking for:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :first_user, foreign_key: :first_user_id, class_name: 'User'
  has_one :second_user, foreign_key: :second_user_id, class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :first_user_games, foreign_key: :first_user_id, class_name: 'Game'
  has_many :second_user_games, foreign_key: :second_user_id, class_name: 'Game'

  def games
    first_user_games + second_user_games
  end
end
```

I think it is probably a bad sign that you need this though, and it will be a pain. Instead you could just add a UserGames table and UserGame join model, put a column called "player_number" on UserGame, and do `has_many :games, through: :user_games` on User to get all games, regardless of player number, and then use queries, filtering, scoping, etc. as needed to find only the games where the player was a certain number. Here are a few questions related to scoping/conditions for `has_many ..., through: ...` on columns in the join model, in case you want to be able to access lists of games in User where the player is a specific player #:

- [Rails complex has_many and has_many through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989680/rails-complex-has-many-and-has-many-through)
- [Scope with join on :has_many :through association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856838/scope-with-join-on-has-many-through-association)